# Form data doesn't get inserted into database

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

When I submit my data from the form, it won't insert the form data in to the database. The connection to the databse is set and when I check the connection it always responds that it is connected. The database is correctly setup with all values: id, name, date, emailadress and text. The username, password and database name are correct.

The syntax should be correct. I work with mysql workbench.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="input.css">

    <header>
      <h1></h1>
    </header>

    <nav>

      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <main>
        <form method="post" action="input.php">
            <label>Name</label>     
            <input placeholder="Name" name="name" type="text"><br>

            <label>Mailadress</label>  
            <input placeholder="Emailadress" name="eMail" type="email"><br>

            <label>Your comment</label> 
            <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Text" name="comment"cols="60" rows="15"></textarea> 

            <input value="Send" type="submit">
        </form>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    if($con->connect_error) 
        {
        die("No connection" .$con-> connect_error);
        }
        echo "Connected";


    $guestbook = new GuestbookAccess();

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $name = $_POST['name']; $eMail = $_POST['eMail']; $comment = $_POST['comment'];  
    }

    class GuestbookAccess
    {
        private $db;

        /**
         * Opens the database.
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $username = "tipuser";
            $password = "TIP2018_WebEngineering";
            $database = "tip";

            // Open the database
            $this->db = mysqli_connect("localhost", $username, $password);        
            if ($this->db == false) {
                die("Unable to connect to database");
            }

            // Select database
            mysqli_select_db($this->db, $database);
        }

       /**
         * Evaluates current time and adds a new guestbook entry with given name, 
         * e-Mail and comment.
         * @param String $name    User name
         * @param String $eMail   User e-mail address
         * @param String $comment The entry text
         * @return On success: Integer Index generated by the database for the entry
         *         On failure: Boolean false
         */
        public function addEntry($name, $eMail, $comment)
        {   
            // For security: suppress SQL injection
            $name    = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $name);
            $eMail   = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $eMail);
            $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $comment);

            // Add entry to the database
            $result = mysqli_query($this->db, "INSERT INTO guestbook (name, email, comment) VALUES ('$name', '$eMail', '$comment')");

            if ($result)
            {
                $result = mysqli_insert_id($this->db);
            }

            return $result;
        }

       /**
         * Return in an table (two-dimensional array) all entries of the guest book.
         * Each row of the table represents one entry in the guest book.
         * @return table[...]["Index"]   --> Integer: Index of the entry (for deleting)
         *         table[...]["Name"]    --> String: name of the user
         *         table[...]["eMail"]   --> String: e-Mail of the user
         *         table[...]["Comment"] --> String: The guest book entry (as text)
         *         table[...]["Date"]    --> String: Date and time of the entry
         */

    public function getEntries()
        {
            // Create query
            $result = mysqli_query($this->db, "SELECT * FROM guestbook");

            $table = false;
            $i = 0;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $table[$i]["Index"]   = $row["indes"];
                $table[$i]["Date"]    = $row["date"];
                $table[$i]["Name"]    = $row["name"];
                $table[$i]["eMail"]   = $row["email"];
                $table[$i]["Comment"] = $row["comment"];
                $i++;
            }

            mysqli_free_result($result);

            return $table;

         // Get all entries in the guestbook
     $table = $guestbook->getEntries();

    if ($table) { // Check if there are enrtries
        echo "\nThe guestbook contains:\n";
        foreach ($table as $row) {
            // Output each element
            $index = $row["Index"];
            $name = $row["Name"];
            $date = $row["Date"];
            $email = $row["eMail"];
            $comment = $row["Comment"];

            echo "Index: $index, ";
            echo "Name: $name, ";
            echo "Date: $date, ";
            echo "eMail: $email, ";
            echo "Comment: $comment\n";
        }
    } 
    else {
        echo "\nGuest book is empty\n";

        }


        /**
         * Closes the database.
         */
         function __destruct()
        {
            mysqli_close($this->db);
        }

    }


    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `$guestbook->addEntry($name, $eMail, $comment)`  to run the function inside `if (isset($_POST['submit'])){`

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server, yet you have `mysqli_connect`. That's clearly a MySQL connector. If you're using SQL Server, you're using the wrong functions.

Comment: Describe your db structure. It seems id is not set to auto-increment and you are not passing id in query.

Comment: One of the things you're not doing, is correctly handing errors. If you handled errors, your script might tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks, adding the function to the if statment generats a database entry. The problem now is that it is empty. It seems I have to check my id for auto-increment, like Sameer said.

Answer (score 1):

You should add name as `submit` for submit type  in your input tage so to make the `isset($_POST['submit'])` work in php

```
<input value="Send" type="submit" name="submit">
```